# Openmp: Have a MASTER construct inside parallel do

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a fortran code that looks like this

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(PRIVATE) SHARED(var1, var2, var3, numberOfCalculationsPerformed)
do ix = 1,nx
  ! Do parallel work
  do iy = 1,ny
    ! Do a lot of work....
    !$OMP ATOMIC
    numberOfCalculationsPerformed = numberOfCalculationsPerformed+1
    !$OMP END ATOMIC
    !$OMP MASTER
    ! Report progress
    call progressCallBack(numberOfCalculationsPerformed/totalNCalculations)
    !$OMP END MASTER
  end do
end do
```

When I try to compile it reports that

> error #7102: An OpenMP* MASTER directive is not permitted in the
>   dynamic extent of a DO, PARALLEL DO, SECTIONS, PARALLEL SECTIONS, or
>   SINGLE directive.

I do not understand this. I have tried to modify the parallel do construct to this

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(PRIVATE) SHARED(var1, var2, var3, numberOfCalculationsPerformed), &
!$OMP& SCHEDULE(STATIC)
```

(in the thought that it had something to do with the scheduling) but that did nothing to change the error.
Does anyone know what I am not getting right? Is it just impossible to use `master` inside a `parallel do` construct or what? If that is so, are there alternatives?

Edit:

```
!$OMP SINGLE 
!$OMP END SINGLE
```

Instead of the `MASTER` equivalent yields the same result... (error message)

Ps. I only need one of the threads to execute `progressCallback`.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. You seem to want to somehow update the progress of the parallel loop, and you think you need the `!$OMP MASTER` directive for that. I think asking more explicitly: "How to best update on progress of an OpenMP parallel loop" might be more helpful.

Comment: Also: If both `numberOfCalculationsPerformed` and `totalNCalculations` are integers, than dividing them will be an integer division, i.e just the integer part of the division. As long as `numberOfCalculationsPerformed < totalNCalculations`, this will always be 0.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't understand this. The parallel do construct means any of the pool of threads may do a given iteration. The master construct specifically says thread zero will do this work. So if, say, thread 3, is assigned the iteration how is the master work supposed to be achieved? Thread zero just isn't active here.

Comment: @Ian Bush Because I only want one (the master thread) to execute the `progressCallBack`. I do not need every other thread to call It, just one of the threads. I think I understand the pooling of threads and how they are set to do one 'ix' iteration each. What I don't get is that I am not allowed to use the `!$OMP MASTER`....  `!$OMP END MASTER`

Comment: A master bock has to be executed by thread zero. Thus a master block must be reachable by thread zero.  But in the do construct you have said that you will share out the iterations amongst the threads. Thus some of the iterations will be dine by threads other than zero. For these iterations it is just not possible for master block to be executed by thread zero, as thread zero has nothing to do with these iterations. Thus what you have is illegal. OMP Single MIGHT do what you want, but it depends crucially on the details.

Comment: I think you are looking for omp critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit old, but since I recently stumbled across the same issue, I wanted to share a simple solution. The idea is to formulate an if-clause which only evaluates to TRUE for one of the threads. This can easily be achieved by querying the current thread number. By requiring it to be zero, the clause is guaranteed to be true for at least one thread:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(PRIVATE) SHARED(var1, var2, var3, numberOfCalculationsPerformed)
do ix = 1,nx
  ! Do parallel work
  do iy = 1,ny
    ! Do a lot of work....
    !$OMP ATOMIC
    numberOfCalculationsPerformed = numberOfCalculationsPerformed+1
    !$OMP END ATOMIC

    if (OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() == 0) then
        ! Report progress
        call progressCallBack(numberOfCalculationsPerformed/totalNCalculations)
    end if
  end do
end do
```

Comment: Thanks for that simple solution! (when reading it is really too simple :).. (why didn't I think of this before.... )

Comment: You  are welcome. If you want a higher frequency of the output, you may change the condition on the threadnumber to be something like OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() < X